# Empty array when making a HTTP Post Request to PHP from Swift App

Tags: php, xcode, swift

Hi I am trying to connect my iOS app to my PHP API.
I am sending JSON POST to my PHP API but I am getting an empty array as Output.

My Swift Code

```
@IBAction func JSONButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
    var usr = "dsdd"
    var pwdCode = "dsds"

    var image : UIImage = clickedPhotoView.image!
    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)

    let params:[String: AnyObject] = [
        "email" : usr,
        "image" : base64String ]

    let url = NSURL(string:"http://localhost/app/")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    let boundaryConstant = "Boundary-7MA4YWxkTLLu0UIW"; // This should be auto-generated.

    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &err)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

       // println("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println("\(responseString)")

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                println("response was not 200: \(response)")
                return
            }
        }
        if (error != nil) {
            println("error submitting request: \(error)")
            return
        }

        // handle the data of the successful response here
        var result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
        //println(result)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

PHP Code

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Output is

```
array(

)
```

But when I use

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

It works fine
I dont know why $_POST is not working.

Comment: Have you tried to set ``request.HTTPBody = params`` where params is NSData with NSASCIIStringEncoding? Currently you are sending just plain text as body where the http protocol expects a ``key=value`` encoding.

Comment: @kekub that solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is actually to send a string, then you should change the content-type:

```
request.setValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Tested your exact code with this modification on my tests server:

[image: Your code works with my server once content-type is changed]

Otherwise, check @kekub's comment.